# How to echo every var more than $var?

Tags: php, xml

I have

```
$room=$_POST['room'];
$lastMTime=$_POST['lastMTime'];

function _getLastMsg($rName, $lMT){
  $r=$rName.'.xml';
  $rXML=simplexml_load_file($r) or die('Not found');
  $rLMT=$rXML->lastMT;
  if($lMT<$rLMT){
    //some code here
  }
}
```

How do I `echo` every `$rXML->username` that has `$rLMT > $lMT`?
I want to get all usernames that have been submitted after `$lMT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the variables into your example you can do this

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 3) {
    $varName = 'var'.$i;
    if ($$varName > $var) {
        echo $$varName;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

But that is no right way to iterate over an array. There exists a million other ways to iterate over a bunch of variables and print them, all of them are not the "right" way to do it. In your example code there is no array, where there should be one. Like this

```
$var = 11;
$vars = [10, 20, 30, 40];

# iterate and echo each element of $vars array)
foreach ($vars as $current) {
    if ($current > $var) {
        echo $var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, but problem i dont know how many elements in the array, i want it to be auto set as they exist in file.xml

Comment: Thanks very much, i understand it now, the array will be the xml itself as it has the vars i want.

Comment: You mean `if ($current > $var) { echo $current; }` , right?

Comment: Yes, i see now from your edit. Yes i meant echo $current, I was careless when I wrote echo $var.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure that all these vars should not be an array instead. When you have multiple variables which are handled in the same way usually it is a clear sign that they should be an array instead.

If not - you can use `compact` function to make variable names into array with their names and values, read [the manual on it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php). Other way to access variable value by its name is [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) - `$$`

Comment: Thanks for helping, It wont be just 3 vars i dont know how many will be.

Comment: @xYuri your edited question differs a lot from original, read the docs on what is returned from `simplexml_load_file` and you should have your answer, if you are familiar with basic concept of looping over a traversable object

Answer (score 1):

may be you can try this code

```
<?php
    $var = [11, 10, 20, 30, 40];

    for($i=0; $i<count($var)-1; $i++) {
        if($var[$i]>$var[($i+1)]) {
            echo "var $var[$i] > var ".$var[($i+1)];
        }
    }
?>
```